# php string becomes null after about 2050 characters added

Tags: php

I have an online database application in which one function outputs a string containing the HTML code for a list of up to 10 records. (This will be the return value for an Ajax call.)

Debugging shows that when the string reaches about 2050 characters it becomes NULL but its length continues to grow. Because records are variable in length, it occurs at various places in the code - though typically on the sixth pass through the loop - and the only common factor seems to be the size of the string.

As I'm using PHP7 I thought there would be no limit on the length of the string.

I'm running the code on a local WAMP server on 64-bit Windows 10 with Netbeans.

A solution or any advice you can give on further tests I can do will be very welcome.

This is the code of the function, in case it helps:

**EDIT**

Code sample removed.

Comment: *"it becomes NULL but its length continues to grow."* -- how did you reach this conclusion?

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: does this happen with another IDE ? or if you set a breakpoint on the return statement ?

Comment: @axiac: I'm reporting what NetBeans watches say.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I don't have another IDE to try it with. A breakpoint on the return value always shows $html as NULL.

Comment: Try `echo`'ing the string. Sounds like a bug with the debugger.

Comment: @MichaelYoo: You're right. See my answer.

Comment: Please the next time past an _easy to reproduce_ example.

Answer (score 2):

My perceived problem was because of NetBeans, not PHP or my code. It seems NetBeans won't display long strings but shows them in watches as NULL. But the data's still there. It wasn't displaying in my code because of a fault elsewhere. An earlier version of NetBeans had [this bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230764) on strings longer than 1024 characters but it seems to have been fixed.